# Expectation value of a path-ordered exponential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions, wick-theorem, wilson-loop

Let us define our path-ordered operator $\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t_2\right)$:

$$
\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t_2\right)=\overrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}\exp\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\,\mathcal{O}\left(t\right).
\tag{2.9}$$

This ordered exponential is a solution of

$$
\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t_2\right)=\mathbb{1}+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\,\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t\right)\mathcal{O}\left(t\right).
\tag{B.1}$$

The expectation value of the trace this operator is

$$
\left\langle\mathrm{tr}\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t_2\right)\right\rangle~\stackrel{(B.1)}{=}~N+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\,\left\langle\mathrm{tr}\left(\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t\right)\mathcal{O}\left(t\right)\right)\right\rangle.
\tag{*}$$

By Wick's theorem you should get

$$
\left\langle\mathrm{tr}\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,t_2\right)\right\rangle=N+N^{-2}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\,\int_{t_1}^{t}d{t}'\left\langle\mathrm{tr}\overrightarrow{U}\left(t_1,{t}'\right)\mathrm{tr}\overrightarrow{U}\left({t}',t\right)\right\rangle\left\langle\mathrm{tr}\mathcal{O}\left(t\right)\mathcal{O}\left({t}'\right)\right\rangle.
\tag{**}$$

I am having troubles to understand this apparently easy-to-get calculation. How does $\mathrm{Tr}\overrightarrow{U}$ appear again inside the correlator?

References:

1. D. Correa, P. Pisani, A.R. Fukelman & K. Zarembo, [arXiv:1811.03552](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03552); Appendix B.

Comment: Possible hint : Novikov theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sketched derivation of OP's eq. (**):*

1. OP's eq. (**) is basically eq. (B.4) in Ref. 1 with the opposite ordering$^1$.
2. In OP's eq. (*) we consider the single-contractions in [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem), see eq. (B.3). The downstairs ${\cal O}(t)$ is contracted with all possible appearances of ${\cal O}(t^{\prime})$ upstairs inside the exponential $\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t_1,t)$. In more detail, the downstairs ${\cal O}(t)$ is contracted with all possible $$\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t^{\prime},t^{\prime}+\Delta t^{\prime})~=~ \exp\left({\cal O}(t^{\prime})\Delta t^{\prime}\right)~\approx~\mathbb{1}+{\cal O}(t^{\prime})\Delta t^{\prime} \tag{i}$$ 
   upstairs in the exponential 
   $$\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t_1,t)~=~\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t_1,t^{\prime})\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t^{\prime},t^{\prime}+\Delta t^{\prime})\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t^{\prime}+\Delta t^{\prime},t).\tag{ii}$$
   [Here $\Delta t^{\prime}$ is assumed small.] In other words, this leads to a sum of the form
   $$ \sum_{t^{\prime}=t_1}^t\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t_1,t^{\prime}){\cal O}(t^{\prime})\Delta t^{\prime}\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t^{\prime}+\Delta t^{\prime},t)\tag{iii}$$ 
   of possible ways to break the exponential $\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t_1,t)$ into two exponentials, cf. OP's last question (v2). [It is implicitly understood that the operator ${\cal O}(t^{\prime})$ in the middle of eq. (iii) is contracted with ${\cal O}(t)$.]
3. Next replace the sum $\sum_{t^{\prime}=t_1}^t\Delta t^{\prime}$ with an integral $\int_{t_1}^t\! dt^{\prime}$.
4. Eq. (2.4) yields that the single-contraction/propagator is of the from
   $$\langle {\cal O}^i{}_j(t){\cal O}^k{}_{\ell}(t^{\prime})\rangle~=~N^{-2}\delta^i_{\ell}\delta^k_j\langle {\rm tr}{\cal O}(t){\cal O}(t^{\prime})\rangle.\tag{iv}$$
   Here $i,j,k,\ell$ are color indices. The two Kronecker-deltas lead to the formation of two color traces of the two exponentials.
5. Putting it altogether leads to the last term in OP's eq. (**). $\Box$

References:

1. D. Correa, P. Pisani, A.R. Fukelman & K. Zarembo, [arXiv:1811.03552](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03552); eqs. (B.3)-(B.4).

--

$^1$ *Notation:* By comparing eqs. (2.9), (B.1) & (B.2) in Ref. 1, it becomes clear that $t_i\equiv t_1\leq t_2\equiv t_f$ always. Moreover, $\stackrel{\leftarrow}{U}_(t_i,t_f)$ and $\stackrel{\rightarrow}{U}(t_i,t_f)$ are (what are traditionally called) the [path-ordered and anti-path-ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential)/[Wilson-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_loop), respectively. Confusingly Ref. 1 call them oppositely: anti-path-ordered and path-ordered exponential, respectively.